# how to execute javascript on server-side?

Tags: javascript

is there a php library or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a few ways of executing JavaScript on the server-side. A recently popular environment is [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). There's also options such as [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (which has [Nitro](http://www.nitrojs.org/) and [Helma](http://helma.org/)). Wikipedia also has a [massive list of server-side JavaScript environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript).

You also asked if there was a PHP extension available. There's one called [php-js](http://aurore.net/projects/php-js/), based upon Mozilla's SpiderMonkey.

Comment: also, this might help too: http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/01/08/rhino-scripting-java-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can execute JavaScript on the server side using Java 6 and Rhino.